# Вынос JSP кода в отдельный файл

Tags: jsp

Имеется код jsp, дублирующийся на трех страницах:

```
<c:forEach var="key"
               items='<%=new String[]{"common.deleted","common.saved","common.enabled","common.disabled","common.errorStatus","common.confirm"}%>'>
        i18n["${key}"] = "<spring:message code="${key}"/>";
    </c:forEach>
```

Задача - вынести его в отдельный jsp-файл и сделать `<jsp include>`.
Пробовал заключить код в тэг code - не помогло. Прошу помощи

Comment: С чем помощи? Выносите и делайте include. В чём проблема-то?

Comment: jsp:include не работает; видимо вставка нужна какая-то другая; а я не могу найти "какая"

Comment: Jsp код надо рендерить отдельно например https://stackoverflow.com/a/32358332/573032